# Choosing three integers to satisfy an equation under a specific condition

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, integers

Find three integers $(a,b,c)$ such that:
$x*a + y*b + z*c = a + b$
**only when** $x = 1, y = 1, z = 0$
where $x, y$ and $z$ can be chosen as any non-negative integers.

For example, choosing $a = 1$; $b = 2$; $c = 4$ fails because then I can choose $x = 3$; $y = 0$; $z = 0$ such that
$x*a + y*b + z*c = 3 = a + b$

Does a solution (choice of $a, b, c$) exist?

For those interested, the practical use of the solution is linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424325/using-the-having-clause-to-identify-groups-with-a-defined-combination-of-records) of trying to use a single summation aggregate in SQL to identify a special occurrence of grouped records.

Comment: Are a,b,c also non-negative? I guess not.

Comment: a,b,c can be positive or negative, but do need to be integers.

Comment: I think the answer to this math question is negative. Just by intuition. But intuition is often misleading.

Comment: Regarding the practical question (since I am also very interested in T-SQL): basically you want to encode a vector of several counts (n1, n2. n3, n4) in a single number M. Imagine these counts have an upper limit L i.e. can be at most L. Then you can encode them all in a single 4-digit (L+1)-base number. E.g. imagine the counts have upper limit 2 i.e. each count is at most 2. Then... the number 2201 in base 3 would mean 2 of type 1, 2 of type 2, 0 of type 3 and 1 of type 4. And it would mean that unambiguously i.e. in a decode-able fashion. Just giving some idea here.

Comment: @peter.petrov great re-statement of the problem from a more practical perspective.  In terms of the problem as I phrased it, correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you're saying if one can assume an upper limit of L for x, y, z then choose a, b, c as successive (L+1)-base numbers and that is the solution.